# jQuery UI sortable not working in iPAD

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-ui

I am using jquery UI sortable functionality. This works fine in browsers. But in touch device such as iPAD it is is not working. Below is the code i am using

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>   
<script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script> 

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".documents" ).sortable();
    $( ".documents" ).disableSelection();
  });
```

My HTML is:

```
        <div id="bodyContainer">
      <ul class="documents">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
            </div>
```

Please let me know the solution asap. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you running on emulator or actual device? It works on my end. Make sure jquery.ui.touch-punch.js gets loaded on IPAD

Answer (score 5):

OK, It is obvious, because jQuery UI library does not include the touch events. If you develop a jQuery powered web site, with using jQuery UI functionalists some of are wont work in touch enable mobile devices. In your case that you have used `sortable()` method is good example.

There is a simply solution you can implement. you can use a **jQuery UI Touch Punch** plugin for overcome this issue (As you used).

Please make sure that your ***jquery.ui.touch-punch.js*** file load or not. I think if it is loading correctly it should work.

Also you can clear the browser cache. (in iPad Settings > Safari > Clear Cookies and Data)

Here is the working example :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>   
<script src="https://raw.github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script> 



<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".documents" ).sortable();
    $( ".documents" ).disableSelection();
  });
</script>

<div id="bodyContainer">
      <ul class="documents">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```