# Input not working on iPad, CSS, LI, div, clipping issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad

[image: https://s11.postimg.org/pxk4mdeoz/example.png]

So I have several inputs sat inside an LI and div that is sortable with jQuery.

The issue here is that on the iPad when I attempt to click into the inputs so that I can make an input, no caret will appear and the input cannot be used.

This is not a generic issue, because other inputs on the page, not wrapped in the LI, do not have this issue.

Moreover, if I click into an earlier input, and then use the 'Next' button on the iPad to move through all the inputs, it will allow me to access and edit the input.

I tried making the z-index very high and I also tried using clearfix but this does not work. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how this might be fixed?

Clearfix:

```
overflow: auto;
zoom: 1;
```

Incidentally the C and X buttons you see in the image also work correctly, so this is just an issue with these specific inputs wrapped

Comment: this answer does not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966006/jquery-ui-sortable-not-working-in-ipad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input').bind('touchstart', function(){
    $(this).focus();
});
```

Fixes the issue.